# save the state of checkboxes in a list

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, checkbox

I have a list with corresponding checkboxes, I would like to save the state of them so I can load the list of checked item when the app runs. How would I do this?

My onRetain looks like:

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return planets;
}
```

With planets being the entire list.

I have read up on SharedPreferences but I can't seem to get it working :(

Comment: try boolean array to store the state of chechbox as per position number

Comment: Do you want to store pemanently or only for that session ?

Comment: try to save it in a boolean array in the customized adapter that you may use to inflate it.

Comment: I want to store it permanently so it only changes when the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: Then you may have to use  database or shared preferences

Comment: Then try to use database or sharedpreferences

Comment: any code snippets? I can't seem to get it working

Comment: then you should use the position as primary key and a boolean value of that position...

Comment: sorry i still can't seem to save the values of the checkboxes, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

database:::
Table name : state_checkBox

Fields
position : int
state : boolean

for code refer this links..

1. [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afVQ04EnX6w)
2. [example Code](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/836467e3-f7aa-499f-a001-5a963ccc6104/?Insert,%20Update,%20Delete%20in%20Android)

you just have to update the state as "true" or "false" in the database but in getview 
all time you have to call a query to setChecked() the checkbox

& you hav to update the database on the checkedchangedlistner() of the checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store in persistence you should use D.B. [like this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

if you want only for the session you should use bundle,  [here in example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Comment: how can I save the list to the database? I have already saved the list to the database but it doesn't save as the checkboxes don't stay checked